# Xpath : Using contains() to search for text containing html tags

Tags: html, xpath

I have a paragraph tag in my HTML document which is of following pattern:

```
<p>
Your email is <strong>some@domain.com</strong>
</p>
```

And i have this Xpath to locate this text:

```
//*[contains(text(),"Your email is <strong>some@domain.com</strong>")]
```

But i wont find it but then i tried this and it works:

```
//*[contains(text(),"Your email is")]
```

I also tried it without any tags and encoding the strong tags in plaintext and it still won't locate it. So how do i use contains to find text that contains further tags within?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that way as xpath doesn't recognize the raw tags. One possible way would be checking text node text and `<strong>` text separately like so :

```
//*[contains(text(), "Your email is ") and strong["some@domain.com"]]
```

Comment: So, Xpath only locates plaintext when we use contains()?

Comment: @hussain yes. Value of an element as recognized by xpath is concatenation of all text nodes within the element (all tags are stripped off).

Comment: @hussain btw, how did you actually do "encoding the strong tags in plaintext"? If the tag is encoded in the HTML then it won't be recognized as tag and you would be able to match it using xpath. But if you meant encoding the tag in your xpath side only, then that's won't work.

Comment: yes i encoded it but only on xpath side which is probably why it didnt work

Comment: but yeah now i have solved it using `//p[contains(text(), "Your email is ") and strong["some@domain.com"]]` and thanks for that :)